# How to assign a string (hyperlink) as 1 and remaining NaN values as 0 in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, nan

```
df['url'] = np.where(df['url'].notnull(), 1, <column no.>)
```

Using this code above puts all values including the `NaN` values as `1` in the column

Comment: post a few rows of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to pandas, but i here are my solutions

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df.loc[new_df['col'].isna(), 'col'] = 0
new_df.loc[new_df['col'] != 0, 'col'] = 1
```

```
new_df = df.fillna({'col': 0})
new_df.loc[new_df['col'] != 0, 'col'] = 1
```

this solutions seem to work just fine, but correct me please in case of error

Comment: Thanks for the code but It is only replacing NaN with 0 but not the links with 1. The links are still present. I want the links to become 1.
       URL
1     facebook.com
2     twitter.com
3     NaN 
4     instagram.com
5     NaN

Comment: That's strange, the links should be replaced by the last line. I checked the code and it worked. Please check dataframe after each operation. Maybe you're using old dataframe in the last `loc` operation

Comment: Works fine now. Thanks for the help. So in case of multiple such columns, will it be ???
new_df = df.copy()
new_df.loc[new_df[[['col','col2','col3']]].isna(), 'col','col1','col2'] = 0
new_df.loc[new_df[[['col','col2','col3']]] != 0, 'col','col1','col2'] = 1